# Is there another way to correct the .geometry.location for Google geocoding API?

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning NodeJs/Express/MongoDB, I am trying to use the Location Google API and get stuck with the fallowing error: ("message": "Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined"), can someone help me, please. Here is the code I use:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const HttpError = require("../models/http-error");

const API_KEY = "BlablablaBlablabla";

async function getCoordsForAddress(address) {

  const response = await axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodeURIComponent(
    address)}&key=${API_KEY}`);

  const data = response.data;

  if (!data || data.status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Could not find location for the specified address.", 422);
        throw error;
      }

  const coordinates = data.results[0].geometry.location;

  return coordinates;
}

module.exports = getCoordsForAddress;
```

Comment: What is the output of `data.results`?

Comment: Can you log `data.results`? It might be `[]`

Comment: I doubt that's related to the issue as that error is about mongo. Maybe that's _an_ issue but since the original error was that you're attempting to access "geometry" on an object that's undefined is the issue. Please dig a bit more and see what is being returned and what you expect to be returned.

Comment: Yes, so sorry @Phix I was confuse this part is not related to the issue. I think that the problem is the fact that I can't reach any of the API property like (results, data, formatted_address, geometry, location, and so one) And have to fine a way to correct my code to get access to them. 

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview

Comment: I try these log but nothing:

const data = response.data;
  console.log(response);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(response.data);
  console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location);

Comment: "but nothing"? Sorry man but I don't know what else to suggest. Is the axios response returning anything? What does the network tab in devtools have to say? Many routes to debug here.